# Eloquent use default value if column is null

Tags: eloquent

I want to use the default value if the column is null. For example:

Settings (Table):

```
id | website_id | column1 | column2
1  |     1      |   null  |  null
```

Website.php:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

class Website extends Model
{
    public function Setting(): HasOne
    {
        return $this->hasOne(IvendiFinanceCalculatorSetting::class)->withDefault([
            'column1' => 'Default',
            'column2' => 0,
```

The above is a hypothetical example, but you can see what I'm attempting to achieve. If I add a row to my table with a matching `website` id, but leave the other columns as `null` I want to return the defaults.

Currently if query the `Website` model with the `settings` relationship I get back the row but `column1` and `column2` is null rather than `Default` and `0`.

```php
dd(Website::query()->with('Setting')->find(1));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`withDefault` works when the relationship is null, not the field values. See [Null Object Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) for more information.

You might be better served by model events, specifically `creating` for when new `IvendiFinanceCalculatorSetting` records are inserted.

Then in the model's `boot` method or an observer class, you can set default setting values:

```
// IvendiFinanceCalculatorSettingObserver.php example

public function creating (IvendiFinanceCalculatorSetting $setting) {
    $setting->setAttribute('column1', 'Default');
    $setting->setAttribute('column2', 0);
}
```

Another approach is setting the default values directly in the model's attribute property:

```
/**
 * The model's default values for attributes.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $attributes = [
    'column1' => 'Default',
    'column2' => 0
];
```

Comment: Didn't see this answer, but I did go along this path but I created a `Trait` which then hooked into the `retrieved` event. Thanks!